# Blog Subsite giving 401 UNAUTHORIZED Message

Tags: 401

I need help and it would be great if anyone suggest/help.

The Problem is:

We added a blog sub-site in a SharePoint 2010 publishing site. now the site is browseable in the authoring version. But it is showing 401 on the public facing, the URL is

http://wwwqa.nextdocs.com/en-us/blogs/default.aspx

instead http://wwwqa.nextdocs.com/ is working.

Do you have any idea how to make the blog site available in the public facing. Well appreciated for help.

Comment: I got a 503, then a 404, then the SharePoint 2010 error trying to get to http://wwwqa.nextdocs.com/en-us/blogs/. Something weird is going on.. :/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a reverse proxy like ISA Server 2006 you likely need to add the new sites to the "public names" tab.

Here is an example of the dialog.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct - my understanding it that the public site tab is for distinct host names and IP addresses. The examples above are "Paths" in my opinion. In any case the OP didn't mention a proxy server.

Comment: Without them in that dialog I am unable to access them from outside the LAN and I receive a 401 unauthorized error. With them in that dialog, I am able to access them fine. Each is a separate site collection. So it is not really a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Benjamin - This wasn't always the case for us. So that might be why it isn't in line with your experience. When we were using HTTP internally we did not need to place individual site collections in that tab. it was only after we switched over to HTTPS and modified the AAMs accordingly. I'm not certain off had exactly what change we made that required that, but I am certain that within our configuration we get 401 unauthorized if the site collections are not explicitly defined there.

Comment: FWIW I have managed a farm with 1000 + site collections and a dozen or so Web apps available over SSL and have never had to manually alter that tab so it *may* be a AAM issue. We have gone off on a tangent from the OPs question though :-)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that only anonymous access is enabled on this Web Application (configurable within "Authentication Providers"), and that the sub site has anonymous access disabled (go to the permissions of the sub site to change this).

Comment: Thanks for reply. No we are not using a reverse proxy like ISA Server. How to enable anonymous access for subsite. Any idea?